# How to use/animate window.scrollTo/$("body").animate() in ReadyMag or if there is any other alternative for this task?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a navbar where I have three options, this navbar is common amongst all pages in my ReadyMag website, here I would like the website to redirect to a "certain" page and scroll a "Y" amount when the "WORK" in the navbar is pressed, which is a `<div>`. This functionality isn't available on ReadyMag.

There are two options in ReadyMag which are similar called "anchor" and "link", but this anchor is set for that page itself.
Which means if I set an anchor, it might work for that "certain" page but when I press "WORK" on other pages, it doesn't redirect to the "certain" page, and only scroll the "Y" distance on that page where I pressed "WORK".
The other open is a back-link, which only redirects you to the "certain" page and *doesn't scroll*.

Below is the code I wrote to use this functionality, HOWEVER, all the console.log() statements work- even the one after the `$().animate()`
Note, that ReadyMag uses `data-id` and hence I've used that along with the various classes.

[This is the official documentation to added custom code on ReadyMag](https://help.readymag.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020844171-Adding-custom-code)

```
<script>
function scrollMe() {
window.location.href = 'https://readymag.com/u3903027759/4476632/#XXS'
   if(window.location.href.indexOf("XXS") > -1) 
     {
       console.log("sixer");
       $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, 0);
     }
     else{
       console.log('bro na')
     }
console.log(window.location.href)
};



$('div.rmwidget.widget-text-v3.no-transition.above-all-fade.fade-in[data id="65454f4dff2316002e2c9962"]').click( scrollMe );
</script>
```

The code executes, "WORK" is being pressed it then fires the scrollMe() function, which redirects us to the new link. After which it prints "sixer" but *doesn't scroll*. Finally it prints the new location ref.

I think it's something to do with ReadyMag's function, if there is even a way to **recruit the native anchor function** it would be helpful.
Thank you, in advance!

Comment: Please feel free to visit the published website, https://readymag.com/u3903027759/4476632 so as to inspect elements